# How do I query a image via a json file with an image path with graphql in Gatsby.js?

Tags: graphql, gatsby, netlify-cms, gatsby-plugin-image

In Gatsby I'm trying to create a query with Graphql to query an image. The image location is set in a homepage.json file (this is being managed by Netlify CMS, so it is dynamic):

```
{
  "homepage_text": "Here goes homepage text",
  "homepage_background": "/images/homepage.jpg"
}
```

The images are located in src/images/

In Gatsby, there are 2 ways of displaying an image:

- StaticImage (which doesn't work for me since the image is dynamic)
- GatsbyImage

My only way is to use GatsbyImage I suppose, I query the homepage information with the following query:

```
query HomepageQuery {
  file(ext: {eq: ".json"}, name: {eq: "homepage"}, childImageSharp: {}) {
    childSettingsJson {
      homepage_background
      homepage_text
    }
  }
}
```

According to the gatsby-plugin-image docs https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-image I need to add the following to the query (childImageSharp and gatsbyImageData). But that's not possible with my example since **it's not the actual image but rather the string that points to the location of the image**. What can I change in my code/query to make it work along with GatsbyImage? (or another suggestion)

```
   homepage_background {
      childImageSharp {
        gatsbyImageData(width: 200)
      }
    }
```

My config.yml:

```
backend:
  name: git-gateway
  branch: master # Branch to update (optional; defaults to master)

media_folder: static/images
public_folder: /images

collections:
  - name: "settings"
    label: "Settings"
    delete: false # Prevent users from deleting documents in this collection
    editor:
      preview: false
    files:
      - name: "general"
        label: "General"
        file: "/content/settings/general.json"
        description: "General"
        fields:
          - { label: "Website title", name: "site_title", widget: "string" }
          - { label: "Favicon", name: "favicon", widget: "image" }
      - name: "homepage"
        label: "Home"
        file: "/content/settings/homepage.json"
        fields:
          - { label: "Homepage Text", name: "homepage_text", widget: "string" }
          - {
            label: "Homepage Background Image",
            name: "homepage_background",
            widget: "image",
            required: false,
          }
```

Plugins from my gatsby-config.js:

```
plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    `gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms`,
    `gatsby-transformer-json`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `settings`,
        path: `${__dirname}/content/settings`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [
          `gatsby-remark-images`,
          `gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe`,
          `gatsby-remark-prismjs`,
        ],
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-postcss`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sass`
  ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed out, in order to use `GatsbyImage` you need to provide a valid node (`childImageSharp`) and in order to create it, you need to tell Gatsby where those images are.

To do so, you need to add a new instance of the `gatsby-source-filesystem` pointing to that path:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `uploads`,
    path: `${__dirname}/static/images`,
  },
},
```

Now, when running `gatsby develop`, in your GraphiQL environment (`localhost:8000/___graphql`) you should see a new node called `allImageSharp` or `allFile` which can be filtered by `sourceInstanceName` (stands for the name in the `gatsby-source-filesystem`):

```
  allFile(filter: { sourceInstanceName: { eq: "uploads" } }) {
    edges {
      node {
        childImageSharp {
          gatsbyImageData
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

---

There's a known issue where NetlifyCMS is not properly setting the relative paths properly and Gatsby is not able to infer directly the image node, hence the `homepage_background` still stands for a string rather than a Gatsby Image node data. Check https://github.com/danielmahon/gatsby-remark-relative-images

---

Disclaimer: ideally, NetlifyCMS is meant to source from a Markdown file, not a JSON, I don't know how this would behave in this approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works in my case. I found a similar solution but I hadn't had time yet to respond. But I think your example also works fine for people who may run into the same issue.